# Titanium Android 3.3: Null pointer on webview

Tags: android, webview, nullpointerexception, titanium

I am trying to pop open a webview in android and I get this:

```
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sceneflix.mobile/org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime:  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime:  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime:  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime:  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime:  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime:  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime:  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime:  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.ensureSubDecor(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:218)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime:  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:116)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime:  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:81)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime:  at org.appcelerator.titanium.TiBaseActivity.onCreate(TiBaseActivity.java:528)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime:  at org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity.onCreate(TiActivity.java:18)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
[ERROR] :  AndroidRuntime:  ... 11 more
```

This is the code that launches the webview:

```
function launchVideo(moviename, url, navgroup) {


    var vidid = "";
    if (url.indexOf("youtube")) {
        vidid = url.split("=")[1];
    }
    var embedurl = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + vidid + '?autoplay=1&autohide=1&cc_load_policy=0&color=white&controls=0&fs=0&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=0';
    Ti.API.info("Playing " + embedurl + " ...");


        var webView = Ti.UI.createWebView({
            url : embedurl,
            enableZoomControls : false,
            scalesPageToFit : false,
            scrollsToTop : false,
            showScrollbars : false,
            disableBounce : true
        });

        var winVideo = Titanium.UI.createWindow({

            title : moviename,
            backButtonTitle : "Go Back",
            barColor : '#000',
            backgroundColor : '#000',
            fullscreen : true,
            orientationModes : [Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT],

        });

        winVideo.addEventListener('android:back', function(e) {
            Ti.API.info("backpushed");
            winVideo.close();
            winVideo = null;
            //Ti.App.fireEvent('android_back_button');
        });

        var button = Titanium.UI.createButton({
            backgroundImage : 'images/backbutton.png',
            top : 0,
            left : 5*dp,
            width : 60*dp,
            height : 30*dp
        });
        button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            winVideo.close();
            winVideo = null;
        });
        var logo = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
            backgroundImage : 'images/logo.png',
            bottom : 5*dp,
            right : 5*dp,
            width : 46*dp,
            height : 46*dp,
            opacity : 0.5
        });

        winVideo.navGroup = navgroup;
        winVideo.add(webView);
        winVideo.add(button);
        winVideo.add(logo);
        winVideo.open({
            animated : false
        });

        winVideo.open();


}
```

As you can likely tell from the navGroup, this is a cross platform app for Android and iOS. 
It works great on iOS, but only android is griefing. Any ideas on this one?

Comment: your code minus the navgroup is working for me on 3.3.0. NavigationGroup has been removed since 3.2.0 and is only for iOS anyway.  Unless you're using something like http://fokkezb.nl/2013/10/21/cross-platform-ui/ to enable NavigationWindow on Android then the navGroup won't work. If that doesn't help, are there any other relevant messages in your error log that you can post?